# zsh: history with cursor at beginning of line

Tags: command-line, zsh

I recently switched from bash to zsh. One (annoying) difference is that when I do Esc-K (in vi editing mode) to move back in command-line history, the cursor is placed at the *end* of the line initially.  I want it to be at the *beginning* of the line initially. How can I get what I want?

Comment: And when the previous history entry contains several lines (zsh's zle makes it less awkward than readline to enter and edit multi-line commands), would you want the cursor to go to the beginning of the first line or of the last line of that multi-line command?

Comment: Because I like it that way -- that's why.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it -- the difference I see between `bash` and `zsh` I is when I `ESC` away from the input mode, then go back and forth with `k` + `j`, `zsh` will put the cursor at the _beginning_ of the last command line, and bash will put it at its end; ie different than what you describe. Better make a movie with `ffmpeg -f x11grab` ;-)

Comment: And btw, Stéphane Chazelas didn't ask you _why_ you want that, but _how_ it should work with multi-line commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, the default mappings for j and k in the vicmd key map are:

```
"j" down-line-or-history
"k" up-line-or-history
```

Remapping them as follows should make them work the way you want:

```
bindkey -a j vi-down-line-or-history
bindkey -a k vi-up-line-or-history
```

Comment: Actually, is `bindkey -M vicmd k vi-up-line-or-history` better?

Comment: I believe they are synonymous. From the man page, `bindkey -a` is a shortcut for `bindkey -M vicmd`. Both operate on the `vicmd` keymap. The latter may be a little more descriptive.